# How to avoid repetition re-declaring variables by calling their methods in Rust?

Tags: rust, variable-assignment

I am using `Into` for multiple arguments in Rust and want to avoid many assignments and stupid mistakes.

```
pub fn my_fancy_function<T>(v: T, u: T, i: T, l: T, j: T)
    where T: Into<MyStruct>
{
    let v = v.into();
    let u = u.into();
    let i = l.into(); // Oops, I transposed these!
    let l = i.into();
    let j = j.into();
    // some code
}
```

Is there a way to avoid writing out large blocks of assignments? A macro might be able to do this:

```
expand_into!(v, u, i, l, j);
```

There is nothing special about the `into()` method, it's just an example where you might often re-declare many arguments at the start of a function in a way that could be easily de-duplicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @paholg noted, you can do this easily with a macro.  However, you *do not* need to use recursion, which will be a little slower and a little less useful (you can only recurse a limited number of times before the compiler just gives up).

I also took the liberty of using the fully-qualified name of the `Into::into` method, to avoid name collision issues:

```
macro_rules! expand_into {
    ($($names:ident),*) => {
        $(let $names = ::std::convert::Into::into($names);)*
    };
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer. I've been working on some pretty intricate macros lately, so I guess I've got recursion on the mind.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do this with a recursive macro:

```
macro_rules! expand_into {
    () => ();
    ($head:ident $(, $tail:ident)*) => (
        let $head = $head.into();
        expand_into!($($tail),*);
    );
}
```

And to test it:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let c = 3;
    let d = 4;

    expand_into!(a, b, c, d);

    // Need to do something that reveals types so the compiler knows
    // which `into()` functions to call.
    if let (Some(x), Some(y), Some(z), Some(w)) = (a, b, c, d) {
        println!("{}, {}, {}, {}", x, y, z, w);
    }
}
```